# How do I create a pop up that lets the user select which cookies they want to enable or disable?

Tags: reactjs, cookies

I'm not looking for the usual, "By using this site...."
Instead I want to code a pop up that'll allow the user to accept all or go through and disable/enable each specific cookie option we use, e.g. Functional, Performance, Marketing, etc.

Currently I've only been able to find WordPress options which is no good as I need to add this to my existing React site.

Something like this:
[image]

Comment: Have a look at [react-cookie-consent](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-cookie-consent).

Comment: Thanks @kkmonlee but this only appears to be for an all or nothing accept, I want to know how to let the users pick and chose cookies.

Comment: Then I would recommend building a system using a library which allows you to capture usage and handle events. You can try using [PostHog](https://github.com/PostHog/posthog-js) - it uses cookies to identify and track users across sessions. [Here](https://posthog.com/tutorials/react-cookie-banner) is a tutorial that might get you started.